# TypeScript can't resolve exported default class

Tags: typescript

I have following module in _M01.ts:

```
export module _M01 {

    export default class Foo {

        constructor () {}

    }

}
```

Then when I want to import the above module in my _M02.ts I get following error:

```
import Foo from "./_M01"; // error "./_M01" has no default export
```

Is it an IDE problem or TS compiler failing or is it just simply me not understanding how this stuff works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the module wrapper around your class in _M01, so this will do what you want

_M01.ts:

```
export default class Foo {
    constructor () {}
}
```

_M02.ts

```
import Foo from "./_M01"; //This works
```

There's more information [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html), but the TLDR versions is that you don't use the Module keyword anymore in TS. You can define a Namespace instead, however for what you need the simple example above is fine.

Comment: I just realized that it is actually written in TS docs, can't believe missed it